# Why are NaN floats?

Tags: floating-point, integer, nan

Division by zero can lead to the apparition of objects, which, while being typed as numbers, are not valid numbers. This led to the creation of [NaNs values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) for numeric data types, mostly used in floating point arithmetic (and hence in most programming `float` types).

Since division by zero could also occur when manipulating integers, why doesn't a 'NaN integer' exist?

I am looking for a documented answer on programmatic constraints explaining this pattern.

Comment: PEPs are python standards, not numpy or tensorflow. If you're looking for a "why", that's not on topic at Stack Overflow, but [this NEP on missing data](https://numpy.org/doc/1.14/neps/missing-data.html) is probably what you're looking for. numpy takes its type definitions from IEEE data type standards - see the [numpy miscelaneous docs on floating point special values](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html#ieee-754-floating-point-special-values) and [IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Comment: I know that PEP are Python standards. I am looking for an explanation in the history of the language or programmatic constraints which justifies not having an integer NaN, which exists in other languages.

Comment: and yeah if you're up for using pandas dtypes, pandas introduced a nullable integer type (type `Int` as distinct from `int`), documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around the idea that the Python developers would have made an explicit choice to not be totally different from other languages. And `None` has been around from the beginning of Python, I believe?

Comment: Wait, you're saying integer nans are normal in other languages? What languages are these?!

Comment: agreed - the programming languages I'm familiar with follow the same standards as python, with no nullable integer types. what language are you referencing?

Comment: Interesting - I was misled by a conversation with a colleague about Java (which I know nothing about) and int NaNs in it (which do not seem to actually exist). I will edit this question to make it more generic, since it is definitely not Python specific.

Comment: @Clef. what about chrslg's answer doesn't address your question? that's I think as close to what you're looking for as you're going to get. I don't think you're going to find a seriously considered proposal to double the memory requirements of every integer, and neither will you find a consideration of "let's just drop the number 255 forever"

Comment: If you're in Python, you could have a look at [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html) for a way to include missing values in integer arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all integers are consistent, have a value.

A 8 bit unsigned integers goes from `00000000` to `11111111`, and all those values have a clear, defined, value, that is from 0 to 255.

Which one of those value would you sacrifice to code a 8 bit unsigned integer NaN? 255 maybe. But then, you sacrifice lot of possible applications. You can't use 8 bits unsigned integer to handle bytes (since they are in [0,256)). Nor use them to manipulate images (white (255,255,255) pixels would be (NaN, NaN, NaN)). Etc.

Not even mentionning all the optimization that becomes impossible if `11111111` unsigned 8bits int means NaN, but `11111111` signed bits int means `-1` (which it has to do)

Sure, you could use 16 bits integer instead. But that would be to need twice as much memory for all those applications (and those happen to be the kind of applicative usage that makes sometimes even 64Gb memory insufficient. I am currently working on a such an application, where my buffer images use all of my 64 Gb. It would be to much cost to half my buffer capacity, just because of a remote possibility that I might need to encode an integer NaN).

Because, that is another reason why it is not so: why would someone need that? I mean, NaN means "Not a number". That is it means that the bits stored in a memory place where a number should be, do not, in reality, represent a number.

It is different for floats. Because classical IEEE encoding of floats makes some combination of bits meaningless (or special). Not much. It is not like it was 1 unused bit, or anything remotely similar. Just a few impossible values among billions of possible ones. But still, some combination of bits are not valid. Or, more precisely, we gave them some special meaning, including NaN.

For int, it is up to you to decide that, for your application, you can sacrifice a value. For example, if you are storing dice outputs, you have more than enough choice to decide that one value (-1, 0, 7, 99, ... anything but 1,2,3,4,5 or 6)  will have a special meaning for you (such as "the dice was not rolled"). The system can't take the responsibility to sacrifice some combination of bits, that is some possible values, to make same special, even for those who don't need any such special value.

For float, well, since there are already a few impossible/redundant combination of bits it cost nothing to give them special names.

Comment: this is both a well thought out answer which is directly speaking to the OP's intent, and also a good demonstration of why this should be closed. while there are good arguments in here for the tradeoffs involved (+1 from me for saving the time to write this all in coments), nothing short of Guido weighing in would definitively answer the question "why doesn't python do this?"

Comment: I disagree that this question should be closed: this answer is clearly not opinion based, but details (very well) programmatic constraints which explain why this choice occurs.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado. Thanks. I would add that Guido had not really his saying into that. This was more a Von Neumann's decision.  And in reality, even he did not really decided it, because it was obvious. Again, like using the same 8 bits to encode 255 and -1. Not just an analogy. An unsigned NaN has to be 255. We can not have a hole in the possible value for integers. A signed NaN has to be either -128 or +127, for the same reason. Preferably -128, for symmetry. So either signed NaN has to be represented differently than unsigned NaN. Or world would have to renounce the `-1≡255` thing.

Comment: And without that, ALU would be need twice more transistors. I am exaggerating of course, since ALU, especially nowadays, do more than ADD, SUB or MUL. But those operations would need to exist in two versions, one for signed, one for unsigned. Because, we could not use 2 complement anymore, if we had int NaN. And that is just one of the problems.

Comment: This answer overstates the case. With eight-bit integers, it might be tough to sacrifice one value for a NaN, but the question asks about integer types generally, not just eight-bit integers. With 16- or 32-bit integers, it is not such a sacrifice. And using 1000000000000000 for a NaN would bring symmetry to the representable values in a signed 32-bit two’s complement integer. It is, as chux’ answer states, more a matter of tried and lost in the market. And it is not clear that, with modern hardware, integer NaNs would not be beneficial and could win a place in the market if tried again.

Comment: Re “That is it means that the bits stored in a memory place where a number should be, do not, in reality, represent a number”: That is the same for integer types of floating-point types, so it does not answer why NaNs are used in floating-point types but not integer types.

Comment: Re “The system can't take the responsibility to sacrifice some combination of bits, that is some possible values, to make same special, even for those who don't need any such special value”: Supporting integer types with NaNs does not require hardware not to support integer types without NaNs. Hardware supports both signed types, by offering different instructions for the different types where needed (e.g., multiply, branch on comparison result).

Comment: @EricPostpischil The quoted part of my comment did not mean that it had to be "hardware" (my usage of the word "system" here was quite generic, not about hard). Just that if there is a 8 bits `NaN`, then there is only 254 non-nan values. And that it would be strange for a "system" (the hard, python, numpy, whatever) to force that on everyone, for the benefit of very few. That was all what I said in the quoted sentence (later, I comment on hardware consideration, but not here).

Comment: As for the fact that hardware supports both signed and unsigned types, yes, indeed. But there would be far less factorization between both if because of NaN we had to renounce 2 complement. There is a reason why 2 complement became universal. Besides, nowadays, having two additioner may not seem a lot. But once upon a time, that was a big deal, and it really mattered that `200+10=210` and `-56+10=-46` was the same operation

Comment: @chrslg: It does not matter if it is hardware or the system; the fact an integer type with a NaN is supported does not mean an integer type of the same width without a NaN cannot be supported.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't a 'NaN integer' exist?

Not worth it.  Formats are Darwinian - only the best survive.  Witness the loss of ones' complement, sign-magnitude, padded unsigned types, non-8,16,32,64,... widths.

There is scant need for an NAN integer type and languages reflect that.

Note that dying ones' complement and sign-magnitude integer encoding could have a -0 or "trap representation or a normal value" in C.  This trap could effect an integer NAN, but nary a soul is asking for that.