# Why pandas prefers float64 over Int64?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column, with 3 unique values: `[0, None, 1]`
When I run this line:

```
test_data = test_data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

the above mentioned column data type is converted to `float64`

Why not `int64`? Technically integer type can handle `None` values, so I'm confused why it didn't pick `int64`?

Thanks for help,

Edit:
As I read about the difference between `int64` and `Int64`, why pandas doesn't choose `Int64` then?

Comment: No, `None` cannot be stored in an int (note `int64` is different to `Int64`). Float is often the safest guess. On such cases, prefer to ad explicit `astype()`

Comment: Pandas uses a process called "upcasting" to determine the data type of a column. You can use `test_data = test_data.fillna(-1)
test_data = test_data.apply(pd.to_numeric)` to convert into **int64**

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi why doesn't it convert to `Int64` then?

Comment: I have no idea. probably because it is too costly to change one type to an other. If int was not good, let's try float, and then object (without trying every subtypes). But I have no idea. There are different trade-off memory/speed (and I think not always done consistently). If you read from a file, I usually specify the dtypes. But I got often surprises (when I forget it, and then loading a new dataset will break everything)

Comment: Because `Int64` is bigger than `float64`. `float64` uses 64 bits. `Int64` uses 72 bits. Again, there is such a thing as `NaN` for float, but not for int (see that [old conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74393426/why-are-nan-floats)). So `Int64` need an extra byte, in addition to the 8 bytes=64 bits to store the int, to store other information, such as a 'NA' flag.

Comment: Note that what you seem to be looking for is the behavior of `convert_dtypes`; it converts a dataframe to the "best" dtype **supporting NA**. If you call `convert_dtypes` on your dataframe (the one using `float64`), it will convert it as `Int64`

Comment: From the docs, [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type), Int64 is a recent, still experimental, data type. As mentioned, since you can;t really have an NA in an integer, it is implemented with a shadow byte array telling whether things are NA. You won't get the same performance as an int or a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is misleading, because you actually want to know why pandas does this, not python. As for pandas, it tries to find the smallest numerical dtype, as stated in the documentation (downcast): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

> downcaststr, default None Can be ‘integer’, ‘signed’, ‘unsigned’, or
> ‘float’. If not None, and if the data has been successfully cast to a
> numerical dtype (or if the data was numeric to begin with), downcast
> that resulting data to the smallest numerical dtype possible according
> to the following rules:
>
> ‘integer’ or ‘signed’: smallest signed int dtype (min.: np.int8)
>
> ‘unsigned’: smallest unsigned int dtype (min.: np.uint8)
>
> ‘float’: smallest float dtype (min.: np.float32)
>
> As this behaviour is separate from the core conversion to numeric
> values, any errors raised during the downcasting will be surfaced
> regardless of the value of the ‘errors’ input.
>
> In addition, downcasting will only occur if the size of the resulting
> data’s dtype is strictly larger than the dtype it is to be cast to, so
> if none of the dtypes checked satisfy that specification, no
> downcasting will be performed on the data.

with code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'int':[1,2],
        'float':[1.0,2.0],
        'none': [1, None]
     }
)
```

you might notice that:

```
print(df.loc[1, 'none'])
# nan
```

returns nan, not None this is because pandas uses the numpy library.
Numpy offers a value which is treated like a number but isn't actually one and is called: not a number (nan), this value is of type float.

```
import numpy as np
print(type(np.nan))
# <class 'float'>
```

Since you used None, pandas tries to find the correct data type, finds numbers with missing values, since it can't handle that it casts it to float where it is able to inser np.nan for the missing values.

Comment: I fixed the issue int he question. It's still not clear to me, why pandas doesn't use `Int64` type then?

Comment: @IshThomas added more explaination, please note that this is only my current understanding of the issue.